# Python Selenium+chrome cannot locate the elements (a table) I want

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to **scrape** the PSI readings from this [website](https://www.haze.gov.sg/resources/readings-over-the-last-24-hours). But no matter whichever selection criterion (id:first-half, class:allow-overflow-item) I use, selenium cannot locate the table and always run the except clause. The webpage can be opened without a problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.haze.gov.sg/resources/readings-over-the-last-24-hours')
try:
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_id('first-half')
    print(elem.text)
except:
    print('Was not able to find an element with that name.')
```

[image: one table looks like this and the source code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `find_elementS` which results in a list of matching elements. Lists do not have `text` attribute. Use `find_element_by_id`:

```
try:
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('first-half')
    print(elem.text)
except:
    print('Was not able to find an element with that name.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the table inside a iFrame?

If it is you'll need to select first that iframe:

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frameNameXXXX"))
```

cheers